# Add column with values after exchange rate conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to write query to add column which calculate values using exchange rate conversion rate from the other table

First table:

| Date | localCCY | ValueinlocalCCY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.06.2022 | Eur | 5000 |
| 02.06.2022 | Gbp | 6000 |
| 01.06.2022 | CHF | 40000 |

Second table

| Date | CCY | USDFactor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.06.2022 | Eur | 0.99 |
| 02.06.2022 | Gbp | 0.9 |
| 02.06.2022 | CHF | 0.95 |
| 01.06.2022 | Eur | 0.98 |
| 01.06.2022 | Gbp | 0.91 |
| 01.06.2022 | CHF | 0.92 |

I would like to write query to get  column with "Value in USD" which convert lo

cal CCY by the rate based on the Date in the first column

| Date | localCCY | Value in USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.06.2022 | Eur | 5050 |
| 02.06.2022 | Gbp | 6666 |

Thank you so much for the support

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? mysql <> sql server. Also as posted this question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple INNER JOIN and application of exchange rate, for either platform.

```
SELECT data.Date,
       data.localCCY,
       data.ValueinlocalCCY / rates.USDFactor AS ValueInUSD
FROM Table1 AS data
INNER JOIN Table2 AS rates ON rates.Date = data.Date
                          AND rates.CCY = data.localCCY;
```

Example for SQL Server:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #data;
CREATE TABLE #data (
  [Date] DATE,
  [localCCY] VARCHAR(100),
  [ValueinlocalCCY] DECIMAL(18, 6)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #rates;
CREATE TABLE #rates (
  [Date] DATE,
  [CCY] VARCHAR(100),
  [USDFactor] DECIMAL(18, 6)
);

INSERT INTO #data ([Date],[localCCY],[ValueinlocalCCY])
SELECT '02.06.2022', 'Eur', 5000 UNION ALL
SELECT '02.06.2022', 'Gbp', 6000 UNION ALL
SELECT '01.06.2022', 'CHF', 40000;

INSERT INTO #rates ([Date],[CCY],[USDFactor])
SELECT '02.06.2022', 'Eur', 0.99 UNION ALL
SELECT '02.06.2022', 'Gbp', 0.9 UNION ALL
SELECT '02.06.2022', 'CHF', 0.95 UNION ALL
SELECT '01.06.2022', 'Eur', 0.98 UNION ALL
SELECT '01.06.2022', 'Gbp', 0.91 UNION ALL
SELECT '01.06.2022', 'CHF', 0.92;

SELECT d.date, d.localCCY, d.ValueinlocalCCY / r.USDFactor AS [Value In USD]
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN #rates r ON r.Date = d.Date
                   AND r.CCY = d.localCCY;
```